# How does MySQL decide if it uses an index for GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table

```
stock_ledger_id   INT(10) (Primary)
piece_to_bin_id   INT(10)
quantity          INT(11)
create_datetime   TIMESTAMP
... and a few VARCHARs
```

with some simple indexes

```
Key_name          Cardinality
PRIMARY               1510443
piece_to_bin_id        100696
```

This rather simple query takes about 8 seconds:

```
SELECT piece_to_bin_id,
       SUM(quantity),
       MAX(create_datetime)
FROM stock_ledger
GROUP BY piece_to_bin_id
```

Here's the EXPLAIN:

```
id select_type table        type possible_keys key  key_len ref  rows    Extra                           
1  SIMPLE      stock_ledger ALL  NULL          NULL NULL    NULL 1512976 Using temporary; Using filesort
```

I found that **I can bring it down to about .5 seconds** by forcing an index:

```
SELECT piece_to_bin_id,
       SUM(quantity),
       MAX(create_datetime)
FROM stock_ledger
FORCE INDEX (piece_to_bin_id)
GROUP BY piece_to_bin_id
```

Then the EXPLAIN looks like this:

```
id select_type table        type  possible_keys key             key_len ref  rows    Extra
1  SIMPLE      stock_ledger index NULL          piece_to_bin_id 4       NULL 1512976
```

I am using MySQL 5.1.41, the table is MyISAM and I did run ANALYZE TABLE before.

So am I stuck with "MySQL got it wrong again, just force the index" or is there an actual reason why MySQL uses a full table scan? Maybe one I can fix?

Comment: both are almost identical, still using full table scan.

Comment: Does your second query run under 1 second even if you use `SQL_NO_CACHE` instruction? (`SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE <rest of the query>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query needs a full table scan anyway, it may be that mysql tries to avoid the additional transition from the key value too the row. The query might much more benefit from a composite (piece_to_ bin_id, create_datetime) index or even  (piece_to_ bin_id, create_datetime, quantity). The latter would become a coverage index.

**UPD**

It seems the 16x faster result comes from the data distribution in your case (probably, many adjacent rows with the same `piece_to_bin_id` sorted by `create_datetime`). MyISAM seems to use indexes for queries which reduce the the number of resulting rows, because using them implies random disk I/O operations.

I have never drawn any attention to it, but my current tests on a table of 10K rows show that MyISAM does not even use the index for sorting a query like:

```
SELECT indexed_field, another_field
FROM a_table
ORDER BY indexed_field;
```

Even when the `indexed_field` is the primary key.

Comment: That doesn't explain why MySQL doesn't use that less appropriate index even though it would make the query 16x faster. However, if I provide it with the coverage index, it does use that index.